# How do I take 3 sets of data in Excel that have no relation to build a crosswalk?

Tags: excel

I have 3 set of data in Excel and what I need to do is to create a crosswalk.  See each set and then my expected results.  I tried to use the Data tab and because there's no relation, I cannot do a query to create it. Would a macros be a possible solution and if so how would that look?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Expected Results but I need to continue on with 3, 4, 5, etc.]

Answer (score 1):

*Updated to adjust for several sheets*

---

Some quick and dirty code :)

You need to set some variable in "Settings" to define where the "tables" are located.

I also "hardcoded" the agreement data/header range due to laziness. For data part:

```
ws4.Range(..., ws4.Cells(outputRow + lrowTypeTXT - 2, outputCol + 5)).Value = ws2.Range(..., ws2.Cells(j, lcolAgreementID + 3)).Value 'Copy Agreement values and paste in column
```

If you want to add one column (for example comment column) you would need to change `+ 5` -> `+ 6` AND `+ 3` -> `+ 4`

**Result:**

ID:

[image]

Agreement:

[image]

Type:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub PopulateData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim lrowID As Long
Dim lrowAgreementID As Long
Dim lrowTypeTXT As Long

Dim lcolID As Long
Dim lcolAgreementID As Long
Dim lcolTypeTXT As Long


'### Settings ###
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set ws4 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")


lcolID = 1 'Column where ID is located, 1 = "A"
lcolAgreementID = 1 'Column where AgreementID is located, 1 = "A"
lcolTypeTXT = 1 'Column where Type is located, 1 = "A"

outputCol = 1 'Column where output should be
'################


lrowID = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, lcolID).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in ID
lrowAgreementID = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, lcolAgreementID).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in AgreementID
lrowTypeTXT = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, lcolTypeTXT).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Type


'copy Headers
ws4.Cells(1, outputCol).Value = ws.Cells(1, lcolID).Value 'Copy ID Header
ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(1, outputCol + 2), ws4.Cells(1, outputCol + 5)).Value = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, lcolAgreementID), ws2.Cells(1, lcolAgreementID + 3)).Value 'Copy Agreement ID header
ws4.Cells(1, outputCol + 1).Value = ws3.Cells(1, lcolTypeTXT).Value 'Copy Type Header


For i = 2 To lrowID 'Loop through each ID
    For j = 2 To lrowAgreementID 'Loop through each Agreement ID
        'Always paste the range of Type, i.e. always paste the nr of rows that exist in column "Type"
        outputRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, outputCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Set last row in output column, update for each agreeement ID
        ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(outputRow, outputCol), ws4.Cells(outputRow + lrowTypeTXT - 2, outputCol)).Value = ws.Cells(i, lcolID).Value 'Copy ID data value and paste in column
        ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(outputRow, outputCol + 1), ws4.Cells(outputRow + lrowTypeTXT - 2, outputCol + 1)).Value = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(2, lcolTypeTXT), ws3.Cells(lrowTypeTXT, lcolTypeTXT)).Value 'Copy Type data values and paste in column
        ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(outputRow, outputCol + 2), ws4.Cells(outputRow + lrowTypeTXT - 2, outputCol + 5)).Value = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(j, lcolAgreementID), ws2.Cells(j, lcolAgreementID + 3)).Value 'Copy Agreement data values and paste in column
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  I had 4 sheets with ranges/tables, how would the code look then? I should have been more specific since these datasets would not be in the same sheet but like you said I didn't specify that so you did it like that

Comment: See if this is working for you. Since the ranges are still fuzzy (are they dynamic/changing/which cells is the data located at...) I have tried to do some general update :). Column width is static so if you want to change that, pls let me know or use the trick I described by changing number.